# Is "Wo ist dein Kamera?" correct? (usage of 'dein/deine')

Tags: gender, adjective-ending, possessive-pronoun

I have a book which has two statements in a problem:

> Du wolltest doch photographieren. Wo ist **dein** Kamera?

I thought *dein* should be changed to *deine* because Kamera is female. Is the second sentence correct?

Comment: Yes, it should be *deine*. Get a different book ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Du wolltest doch fotografieren. Wo ist deine Kamera?

Is correct. Not 'ph' but 'f'.
You will (actually) always use 'deine' when the reference is feminine. When it is masculine or neutral it is just 'dein'.

> Deine Freundin
>
> Dein Freund
>
> Dein Auto

Comment: In English we distinguish between "male/female" sex, and "masculine/feminine" grammatical gender.

Comment: @fdb Yes sorry you are right. The op used female and I just carried that word over. I had latin and of course we used feminine and masculine as well. I fixed that in the answer. Thanks for noticing me.

Comment: I still write _Photo_ etc and don't consider it wrong, even though _Foto_ certainly has been the more popular variant in recent years.

Comment: @Ingmar Indeed it isn't wrong. But it is a rather some old fashioned style (reform of 1996). 'Foto' is modern and way more common for younger generation. It seems that the learning book is some older probably.